# guide for UIScrollView and autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am struggling with `UIScrollView` and AutoLayout. I [read a blog](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/) and tried to do my own stuff. However, Xcode is reporting ambiguous content size. I setup the `scrollview` and leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints to 0 from super view.

There is a `UIView` as container to hold all of my sub views, including two `UILabel` elements and two `UICollectionView` views. I set the container view as equal width and equal height with the View controller's view. Then I set the `UILabel` and `UICollectionView` views constraints all to 0. However it runs as the below picture.

Please help me or give me some doc or guide on `UIScrollView` and AutoLayout.

> [image: The constraints]
>
> [image: problems]
>
> [image: screnshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that the contents of the scrollView (i.e. your container view) are not pinned to the scrollView.

Here is what I suggest:

1) Remove the constraints for the width and height of your container view.

2) Pin the container view's left, top, right, and bottom to the scrollView's left, top, right, and bottom.  By doing this, however big your container view is, that will define the scrollable area of the scrollView.

3) If you just want your content to scroll vertically, constrain the width of the container view to the scrollView's width.

4) You'll need to specify the container view's height.  You can do this by just giving it a fixed height constraint.  Make sure it is bigger than the scrollView height, or there will be nothing to scroll. The other way to do it is to make sure that its content views sizes are fully specified and that the top most view inside the container view is pinned to the top of the container view, and the bottom most view in the container view is pinned to the bottom, and the views should be pinned to each other vertically.  In other words, you should have enough constraints inside your container view for Auto Layout to be able to compute the height of your container view.

Comment: Thanks! I removed all and start over again. Seems working, however, the collection view(inside container view)'s height is calculated by how many cells are there, so I cannot know until I get all the data for cells. How do I deal with this, say, programatically change the constraint?

Comment: You can change a constraint programmatically by adding an `IBOutlet` to the constraint in your code.  Control drag from the constraint in the Document Outline view to your code, and give it a name like `collectionViewHeight`.  Then you can update it like this:  `collectionViewHeight.constant = 300`.

Comment: where should i update it is proper? Layoutsubview or any others?

Comment: Update the constraint when you know the height of your collectionView, then call `layoutIfNeeded` on the collectionView.

Comment: I read about Apple's document about setting the constraint as a placeholder, I fell it is my case since my collection view's height will change after cells are created. I did select collection view's height constraint as place holder, however when running, the whole collection view is not appearing. Before this, I can see it. What else should I do after setting it as place holder?

Comment: If you make the constraint a placeholder, then what is providing the height of the collection view at run time? Could you provide a link to the Apple documentation to which you refer?

Comment: check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutolayoutPG.pdf and search Content Size Is Undefined, it will show you.   My understanding is if it is a place holder, at run time the collection view height will be set as contentSize.height automatically.  However it seems not true.

Comment: You are applying the placeholder constraint to a collection view?

Comment: I don't think this will work because collection views show their cells inside of its own scroll view. Adding more cells doesn't ,

Comment: Make the collect view controller taller, it just scrolls to show the content.

Comment: the whole view height become zero becasue the place holder，so still need constraint property to update it