# CollectionView in ScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I am working on an iOS app where I want to show a `UIScrollView` with two `UILabels` an `UIImageView` and a `UICollectionView` at the bottom. Now I don't know how to do this in auto layout, who could help me out?

I've tried just adding everything and setting the constraints to each other, but I do remember that the `UIScrollView` needs to calculate the intrinsic content height. How can I create this scroll view?

Comment: Make sure you have a connected chain of views from top to bottom of your scrollView.  If you set the spacing to the top of the scrollView for the topmost item, spacing to the bottom for the lowest item, set spaces between intervening items, and all items have specified heights, iOS will be able to compute the size of your scrollView.

Comment: I also suggest you add a container view that holds the entire content of your scrollView.  This makes it easy to restrict the scrolling to just vertical on all devices. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28048228/1630618

Comment: Alright, but if I set my collectionView.height = 200, that means I can't see the items that are below the 200 points, right?

Comment: A collectionView is a subclass of a scrollView and it scrolls to show its contents.  Would it be enough to just let the collectionView scroll, or do you really want to contain it in a scrollView and have your labels scroll offscreen?

Comment: I would actually like to scroll the labels off screen

Comment: Maybe I could actually solve it just by using a collection reusable view as header, right?

Comment: Yes.  I think that would work.  Otherwise, you'll have to programmatically update the height constraint for your collectionView as the content changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid embedding the `UICollectionView` into a `UIScrollView` in this case. It will be easier to add the `UILabel`s and `UIImageView` into a section header using a `UICollectionReusableView` subclass.

Here are the steps:

1. Add a section header to the `UICollectionView`:

[image]

2. Create your section header view class by subclassing `UICollectionReusableView`. Set custom class and reuse identifier of the header reusable view:

[image]   [image]

3. Lay out your header view. Connect your outlets.
4. Implement the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method.

   ```
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

       // If you also use footers:
       // use a switch statement on the 'kind' argument to
       // decide which view to dequeue.

       let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath)

       // set up your header view

       return view
   }
   ```